# Not able to get .listview('refresh') and .trigger( "updatelayout") working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm using Ajax to retrieve data and populate my list. But I'm not able to get jQuery Mobile to add the classes needed to style my list, or refresh the list 
if I do a new search (old results is still in list).

I've found plenty of similar Q/A's here on Stack, but none of the solutions work. I've not implemented the entire solution [found over at jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/), but I believe this should work anyway?

Am I building the list wrong? [I have a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/etsg4vvw/8/)

```
// HTML
<ul id="brandList" class="front" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>

// JS
var el = Part.mainSearchResult();

$(response.brands).each(function(){
    var brand = $(this)[0];
    var url = '/brand?id=' + brand.id;
    var li = $(el.brand).clone();

    $(li).find('a').prop('href',url);
    $(li).find('a').text(brand.name);
    $('#brandList').append(li);
});

$('#brandList').listview('refresh');
$('#brandList').trigger( "updatelayout");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your Fiddle had a mistake, you had the UL in the CSS section.

Was in the CSS Section, not HTML:

```
<ul id="mylist" class="front" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

Seems to be working and is adding the classes to the UL.

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph5p4pwj/)

**EDIT:**

You need to call `$('#mylist').listview( "refresh" );` inside the test function

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3p7v7uLp/)

Comment: Thanks. Just tired. I've updated the link and my question. The real question is why jQuery Mobile does not append styles and refresh list though.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on - but I swear I've tried that! But your magic works. Thanks. Do you by any chance know how I can update the ui-search panel? When my list is long it goes beyond my list panel. See http://prntscr.com/5z3wgc. Also, old searches do not get removed from list: http://prntscr.com/5z3xdm. I've fixed both these problems with custom code, but I was hoping JQM handled this.

Comment: @Steven NP. I have had my fair share of times like that! You should be able to use the same type of logic. $('selector').panel('refresh'). <-- I could be wrong on that. Could you make another question and post some code?